# Extend Mockery::on assertions for common Use Cases

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, mockery

Is extending [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery) for commonly used assertions possible?

Asserting that a mocked function receives an instance of a class AND matching an identifier is cumbersome.

```php
Mockery::on(
  fn ($arg) => $arg instanceof App\Models\User && $arg->id === $user->id
)
```

### Is it possible to...

1. Simplify this call by extending Mockery (via a Macro?) so that this assertion could be `Mockery::onUser($user)` or `Mockery::onUserOfId($id)`?
2. Pass in multiple arguments like `Mockery::onUserOfRole($id, $user->role)`?

*Note: the `$user` object instance provided to the `Mockery::on` call in the Test is **not** the same instance as is passed to the mocked function being tested, hence checking the type and matching the identifier.*

### Possible Solution ... that's not flexable

A possible solution we have explored is extending the base `TestCase` class with a `matchModel()` function, but this extension is not "elegant". I have considered breaking it out into a Trait, but attaching these functions to all Test Cases, `$this->onUserOfRole()` seems wrong. The solution also fails or needs to be customized. (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model@is()` works, but...) if the Object is not a Laravel Model, then we're back to square one:

```php
# Possible Solution that is not extensible and only works on Models
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
    protected function matchModel(Model $model)
    {
        return new MockeryClosure(function ($arg) use ($model) {
            if ($model->is($arg)) {
                return true;
            }

            // print custom error message

            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mockery::on method](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/blob/9ad050f4d5c838e60885d56f808dcafc56383805/library/Mockery.php#L451) is just a one-line wrapper around the constructor for [the `\Mockery\Matcher\Closure` class](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/blob/9ad050f4d5c838e60885d56f808dcafc56383805/library/Mockery/Matcher/Closure.php), which in turn defines only two pieces of custom logic:

- a `match` method which takes the parameter being examined, and returns true or false
- a `__toString` method returning the fixed string `'<Closure===true>'`, presumably for use in error/debug messages

The actual closure isn't defined directly as a property, it just relies on [the constructor inherited from `MatcherAbstract`](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/blob/9ad050f4d5c838e60885d56f808dcafc56383805/library/Mockery/Matcher/MatcherAbstract.php#L37) which sets an untyped property `$_expected`, but performs no other logic directly.

So a replacement for your use case can simply over-ride that constructor with whatever arguments you want, and use them in the `match` method to implement your test, e.g.

```
class MyMatcher extends Mockery\Matcher\MatcherAbstract
{
    private string $expectedClass;
    private string $keyName;
    private mixed $keyValue;

    public function __construct(string $expectedClass, string $keyName, mixed $keyValue)
    {
        $this->expectedClass = $expectedClass;
        $this->keyName = $keyName;
        $this->keyValue = $keyValue;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the actual value matches the expected.
     *
     * @param mixed $actual
     * @return bool
     */
    public function match(&$actual)
    {
        return
            is_a($actual, $this->expectedClass, true)
            && 
            $actual->{$this->keyProperty} === $this->keyValue;
    }

    /**
     * Return a string representation of this Matcher
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "<Is {$this->expectedClass} and has {$this->keyProperty} of {$this->keyValue}>";
    }
}
```

Then this:

```
Mockery::on(
  fn ($arg) => $arg instanceof App\Models\User && $arg->id === $user->id
)
```

Becomes this:

```
new MyMatcher(App\Models\User::class, 'id', $user->id)
```

If you want to shorten the `new MyMatcher` further, you can put a function wherever you like that wraps it in the same `Mockery::on` wraps `new \Mockery\Matcher\Closure`.

If you want more complex or configurable tests, all you need to figure out is a way to return a boolean result from `match`.